# How to use interrupt() in this context

Tags: java, multithreading

If run() hasen't finished and is recalled from outside I need to finish the running shread first.

```
public class EnvTime extends Thread {
    public void run() {
        long step = 2000 / benvelope1.length;
        while (!finished) {
            for (int i = 0; i < benvelope1.length; i++) {
                envOut = benvelope1[i];
                try {
                    Thread.sleep(step);
                } catch (InterruptedException benvelope1) {
                    benvelope1.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

So I call this code from another method with:

```
Env interpol;

interpol.interrupt(); //

interpol=new EnvTime();

interpol.start();
```

But this is not working...

Answer (score 1):

It's not clear what you're trying to achieve, but by doing

```
Env interpol;

interpol.interrupt(); //
```

you'd probably get a `NullPointerException`. If you want your code to reach the

```
} catch (InterruptedException benvelope1) {
    ...
}
```

you need to make sure the thread is in the `try`-block, specifically in the `Thread.sleep` method when you interrupt it.

In other words, you at least need to **start the thread** before interrupting it.

Answer (score 0):

You should change `finished` somewhere in your code. 
Like this way:

```
        try {
            Thread.sleep(step);
        } catch (InterruptedException benvelope1) {
            finished = true;
            benvelope1.printStackTrace();
        }
```

Maybe you should also wait that the thread is really terminated before starting the new one. Use join:

```
interpol.interrupt(); 
interpol.join();
interpol=new EnvTime();
interpol.start();
```

Comment: thanks, I will try that. for some reason I can't wait for the thread to finish. I need to force a finish